# Is there a way to resend UDP packets using Twisted?

Tags: python, proxy, udp, twisted, forwarding

Problem: Simple UDP proxy - receive UDP packets from multiple sources on port X and forward (resend) them to IP Y on port Z.

Description: I am able to create a simple UDP server using twisted, and receive incoming packets easily. However, I cant find a way to resend these packets (their data) further, using Twisted. Is there a specific, kosher and Twisted-like way of doing that in twisted, or should I use simple python sock.sendto way in the method that handles received data in Twisted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do something like this:

```
class MyProtocol(DatagramProtocol):
    def datagramReceived(self, datagram, addr):
        # use self.transport.write to send stuff
        some_where = ('192.168.0.1',5001)
        self.transport.write( datagram, some_where )
```